# Does Heroku Support Lombok?

Tags: spring, heroku, lombok

I have an application which reads `Json` data using `WebClient`. I have deployed the same on `Heroku`.
So I used `lombok` library to parse Json to Java Object.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class member {

//properties
}
```

If I use `lombok` and deploy the same on heroku, I'm not receiving data whereas If remove `lombok` and use normal `Getters` and `Setters`, then it is working as expected!

Is that mean `heroku` is not supporting `lombok`? I couldn't find anywhere in the official document. Or Do i need anything to support `lombok` on `Heroku`?

Comment: Have you tried to run lomboked version in your local. I think it could be smth do with your build process. As far as I know lombok is changing the classes during build time. That means in the final jar everything as you know it. The only possible issue could be smth do with build configuration, Which build tool are you using , maven? If so I suggest you to take a look at this one https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven

Comment: In local it is working as expected. what do u mean lomboked version? I'm using gradle. i have added `compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'` in build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add lombok plugin into your gradle configuration like this

```
plugins {   
   id "io.freefair.lombok" version "5.1.0"
}
```

so that the annotations will be processed properly.

Comment: yea.. working.. but can u explain elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: This plugin processes the annotations to introduce changes into your class files. When you use your IDE during development most likely annotation processing has been done by IDE.That is why it was working without any issue. But when you want to build the executable jar/binary it should be done by gradle. That is why you need this one.